# Display MySql Data From Linked Tables using Id

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables - events and attendees.

I am trying using php to when clicking on the attendee's list via the events.id and to display the attendees listed in the attendees table linked by id.

fields envolved are events.id and attendees.id and to display the attendees for that event.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
SELECT events.*, attendees.* 
FROM attendees ON event.id = attendees.id 
WHERE event.id = attendees.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your joining syntax is an incorrect mix of implicit and explicit `JOIN` syntaxes, missing the `JOIN` keyword, and instead duplicating the join condition in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
  events.*, 
  attendees.* 
FROM
  attendees 
  JOIN events ON event.id = attendees.id
WHERE
  event.id = <event to find attendees for>
```

Note that it is *not advisable* to use `events.*, attendees.*` in PHP, since you will have duplicate column names that become inaccessible to PHP.  Instead, be explicit:

```
SELECT
  /* Be explicit about the columns you select in a JOIN query */
  events.id AS event_id,
  events.name AS event_name,
  events.someothercol,
  attendees.id AS attendee_id,
  attendees.name AS attendee_name
FROM
  attendees 
  JOIN events ON event.id = attendees.id
WHERE
  event.id = <event to find attendees for>
```

If you still want to get the event details even if it has no attendees, use a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT
  /* Be explicit about the columns you select in a JOIN query */
  events.id AS event_id,
  events.name AS event_name,
  events.someothercol,
  attendees.id AS attendee_id,
  attendees.name AS attendee_name
FROM
  events
  /* LEFT JOIN will return event details even when there are no attendees */
  LEFT JOIN attendees ON event.id = attendees.id
WHERE
  event.id = <event to find attendees for>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two tables like this:

```
events:  
  ID  
  ...  

attendees:  
  event  
  ...
```

And you need to get a list of attendees associated with their events, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM attendees LEFT OUTER JOIN events ON attendees.event = events.ID
```

If not, please clarify your question.